# How do you add more than one provisioning profile on nevercode.io

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-app-extension

The documentation on nevercode.io (https://developer.nevercode.io/docs/code-signing#section-provisioning-profile) states correctly that each app extension will need it's own provisioning profile.How can I add more than one provisioning profile when using the manual code signing method?[image: code signing only allows for one provisioning profile]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since NeverCode.io hasn't updated their documentation, I'm documenting it here.  It's quite easy, and unfortunately, somewhat unintuitive.

Once the code repository has the App Extensions, navigate to the  Project Settings [image: project Settings]

then "Build" on the left-hand side. Click on "rescan projects".[image: Build configuration]

Once this is complete, you should be able to return to the "Code Signing" section and add as many profiles as you need.
[image]